# Security headers break Outlook.com add-in in IE11

Tags: nginx, outlook, http-headers, internet-explorer-11, outlook-addin

When I try to run my Outlook add-in in Outlook.com in IE11 I see this.

[image: Add-in Error]

The errors in the console don't seem related to my code.

[image: SEC7111]

I think this could be related to the headers I'm using. But without detailed error messages, I dont know what to change (I'm not an expert with headers).

Here are the headers I'm using:

`Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com https://api.mixpanel.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src 'self' https://*.mysite.com https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com; connect-src 'self' https://*.mysite.com https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com https://api.mixpanel.com; frame-ancestors *
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 09 Feb 2018 14:15:38 GMT
ETag:W/"5a7da721-30e"
Last-Modified:Fri, 09 Feb 2018 13:50:25 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.12.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:ALLOW-FROM https://outlook.mysite.com https://outlook.live.com
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block`

Its worth noting that, under the network tab, I'm able to see the html page. Its been fetch as a 200.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one "ALLOW-FROM" in IE11. So instead of

`X-Frame-Options:ALLOW-FROM https://outlook.mysite.com https://outlook.live.com`

I had to do

`X-Frame-Options:ALLOW-FROM https://outlook.live.com`